# PHP mobile detect - echo header possible?

Tags: php, html, mobile, detect, head

I'm using php for mobile detect including header refresh. However I wondered if it's possible to echo the head tags and DOCTYPE instead. Unfortunately the page seems to be loaded way before the device is detected. Any idea how to fix it? Here is the script, THX in advance!

```
    <?php
$tablet_browser = 0;
$mobile_browser = 0;

if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*(mobi|opera mini)))/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
$tablet_browser++;
}

if (preg_match('/(up.browser|up.link|mmp|symbian|smartphone|midp|wap|phone|android|iemobile)/i', strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

if ((strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT']),'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml') > 0) or ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE']) or isset($_SERVER['        HTTP_PROFILE'])))) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

$mobile_ua = strtolower(substr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 0, 4));
$mobile_agents = array(
'w3c ','acs-','alav','alca','amoi','audi','avan','benq','bird','blac',
'blaz','brew','cell','cldc','cmd-','dang','doco','eric','hipt','inno',
'ipaq','java','jigs','kddi','keji','leno','lg-c','lg-d','lg-g','lge-',
'maui','maxo','midp','mits','mmef','mobi','mot-','moto','mwbp','nec-',
'newt','noki','palm','pana','pant','phil','play','port','prox',
'qwap','sage','sams','sany','sch-','sec-','send','seri','sgh-','shar',
'sie-','siem','smal','smar','sony','sph-','symb','t-mo','teli','tim-',
'tosh','tsm-','upg1','upsi','vk-v','voda','wap-','wapa','wapi','wapp',
'wapr','webc','winw','winw','xda ','xda-');

if (in_array($mobile_ua,$mobile_agents)) {
$mobile_browser++;
}

if (strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']),'opera mini') > 0) {
$mobile_browser++;
//Check for tablets on opera mini alternative headers
$stock_ua = strtolower(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA'])?$_SERVER['HTTP_X_OPERAMINI_PHONE_UA']:(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA'])?$    _SERVER['HTTP_DEVICE_STOCK_UA']:''));
if (preg_match('/(tablet|ipad|playbook)|(android(?!.*mobile))/i', $stock_ua)) {
  $tablet_browser++;
}
}

 if ($tablet_browser > 0) {
$doctype = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN\" \"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd\">";
$tags = "\t<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"user-scalable=no,     initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width\">\r\n\t<meta name=\"apple-mobile-web-app-capable\" content=\"yes\" \/>\r\n\t<meta name=\"apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style\" content=\"black\" \/>\r\n\t<meta name=\"format-detection\" content=\"telephone=no\" \/>\r\n\r\n\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"mstyle.css\" type=\"text\/css\" media=\"screen, projection\" \/>";

else if ($mobile_browser > 0) {
$doctype = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//WAPFORUM//DTD XHTML Mobile 1.2//EN\" \"http://www.openmobilealliance.org/tech/DTD/xhtml-mobile12.dtd\">";
$tags = "\t<meta name = \"viewport\" content = \"user-scalable=no,     initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width\">\r\n\t<meta name=\"apple-mobile-web-app-capable\" content=\"yes\" \/>\r\n\t<meta name=\"apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style\" content=\"black\" \/>\r\n\t<meta name=\"format-detection\" content=\"telephone=no\" \/>\r\n\r\n\t<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"mstyle.css\" type=\"text\/css\" media=\"screen, projection\" \/>";
}

else {
$doctype = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"    \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">";
$tags = "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"style.css\" type=\"text/css\" media=\"screen, projection\" />";
}

?>



<!--    DOCTYPE, HTML, HEAD   -->

<?php echo "$doctype"; ?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="favicon.ico">
<script src="js/upload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/clipboard.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<title>AE46 Upload</title>

<?php echo "$tags"; ?>

</head>
```

Comment: You are using "php for mobile detect". I've googled that to find out what you're really using. Is it this: http://mobiledetect.net or this: http://detectmobilebrowsers.com ? Information you don't provide has to be guessed, that makes answering your question difficult.

Comment: Please, add code that you use to detect mobile.

Comment: Code is updated. THX so far!

Comment: Inform @wormi4ok and other one about it.

Comment: Do you use any framework? If no, try set `$doctype` hard, without any conditions. Maybe your `preg_match` patterns doesn't do their job, so you always get `else` branch when setting `$doctype` and `$tags`